# None is not callable KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivymd

I am trying to shift to screen in my code from my python file from dynamically added 'onelineavatarlistbuttons'
but i cant change screen from them

my code

```
def on_start(self):
    list_item = ObjectProperty
    list_item = [] 
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect('friend_list.db')
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor() 
    self.cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM friend_list ;""")
    self.connection.commit()
    for name in self.cursor.fetchall():
        list_item = [name]
        button = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text = str(name).strip('(').strip(')').strip(" ' ").strip(",").strip("'"),on_press = self.change_screen("Chat_Screen"))
        self.root.ids["Chat_List"].ids["list"].add_widget(button)

    if name not in list_item:
        a = list_item[-1]
        button = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text = str(a).strip('(').strip(')').strip(" ' ").strip(",").strip("'"),on_press = self.change_screen("Chat_Screen"))
        self.root.ids["Chat_List"].ids["list"].add_widget(button)

def change_screen(self,screen_name):
    screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
    screen_manager.current = screen_name
```

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal? Always show full error in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Comment: `on_press` needs function name without `()` and argument and when you press button then it will use `()` to execute this function. if you need function with argument then you may need to use `lambda` for this `on_press=lambda: self.change_screen("Chat_Screen")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_press` needs function name without `()` and without arguments - so called `"callback"` - and when you press button then it uses `()`  to execute this function. It also send clicked `widget` as argument so you can recognize which button was clicked and you can get ie. text from widget.

If you have to assing function with argument then you may need to use `lambda` for this. Because it

```
on_press=lambda widget:self.change_screen("Chat_Screen")
```

or with sending `widget` to function

```
on_press=lambda widget:self.change_screen("Chat_Screen", widget) 

def change_screen(self, screen_name, widget):
    print(widget)
    # ... code ..
```

---

And this moment your code execute function at start and it works like

```
result = self.change_screen("Chat_Screen")
on_press=result
```

Because `change_screen` doesn't use `return` so it returns `None` and you get

```
on_press=None
```